# php not honoring newline

Tags: php, php-5.4

I am running php 5.4.16 on CentOS7.  I am trying  to create a multiline file.  According to the php syntax I have it correct, but it does not honor the newline.  Right now I am going back to basic and just using the example on the php site, and it still does not work.  What am I missing?
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

my output is :
My name is "MyName". I am printing some Foo.Now, I am printing some Bar2.This should print a capital 'A': A

```
 echo <<<EOT
    My name is "$name". I am printing some $foo->foo.
    Now, I am printing some {$foo->bar[1]}.
    This should print a capital 'A': \x41
    EOT;
    ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `newline`? Do you want a line break on the output? If so, insert one.

Comment: I would like it to display the way it is.  Meaning after "foo." starts a newline and after "}." another newline.  Unless I read the documentation wrong that is how it should work.

Comment: Are you viewing the result on the command line, or in a browser? On the command line, it should have line breaks alright. In a browser it won't unless you prepend a `header('Content-Type:text/plain');` or use `<br />`s as line breaks.

Comment: In HTML a newline would be `<br/>`. On console, a newline would be `\n`. As such, how is the PHP to implicitly know what you mean (logically) by newline. I think you are going to have to explicitly insert the newline characters you desire.

Comment: Please upgrade PHP as soon as possible. This version hasn't been supported in ages.

Comment: If the output you're referencing is in the browser, you can press Ctrl+U to open the source code (Windows, Linux) or Option+Command+U in Safari on Mac. In the source code, you'll see the text output, likely with the newlines.